# Colon operator in List Slicing

Tags: list, machine-learning, numpy-slicing, mini-batch

```
mini_batch_X = shuffled_X[:, k * mini_batch_size:(k + 1) * mini_batch_size]
```

What is the semantics of the above line? what does the first colon mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Colon in a slicing operation will generate `slice(None, None, None)`, in numpy it means `take all indices for this dimension`.

A slice is `start:end:step`, usually step is omitted writing only `start:end`, but you can also omit start `:end` that will slice from beginning, or `start:` that will end at the last index.